# Docker stack deploy multiple errors from container on docker hub

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and trying to understand what docker stack does. Currently trying out this container https://hub.docker.com/r/instapy/instapy

this is the docker-compose file

```
services:
  web:
    image: instapy/instapy:latest
    container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_web"
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0
      - INSTAPY_WORKSPACE=/code/InstaPy
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
```

The errors I'm getting seem to indicate quite a few issues

```
Ignoring deprecated options:

container_name: Setting the container name is not supported.

service "web": container_name is deprecated
service "web": env_file are ignored
Stack.compose.docker.com "test" is invalid: test: Invalid value: "null": conversion to kube entities failed: C:\Users\roole\instapy-docker\docker-compose: only absolute paths can be specified in mount source
```

docker compose version info

```
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b
docker-py version: 3.7.3
CPython version: 3.6.8
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018
```

Content asked for from ' docker-compose config'

```
services:
  web:
    container_name: instapy_web
    environment:
      COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME: instapy
      INSTAPY_WORKSPACE: /code/InstaPy
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: '0'
    image: instapy/instapy:latest
    volumes:
    - C:\Users\roole\instapy-docker\docker-compose:/code:rw
version: '3.0'
```

Any help in understanding what the hell I'm supposed to be doing would be mega.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of each docker-compose.yml file you need to specify the version. Each version of docker-compose supports certain versions of the yml file specification.

This should work for you:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  web:
    image: instapy/instapy:latest
    container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_web"
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0
      - INSTAPY_WORKSPACE=/code/InstaPy
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
```

Comment: My bad, I missed off the version when adding it to this post. it was version 3 tried 3.3 same results.

Comment: What version of docker-compose are you using? Also can you post the result of 'docker-compose config'

Comment: Docker-compose version 

docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b
docker-py version: 3.7.3
CPython version: 3.6.8
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018

Can't see to see where the config file for it is. This is all being done with Docker Desktops latest stable build though.

Comment: I now noticed you are trying to deploy a stack.... my bad. I will add a new answer. sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

When deploying a stack the container name is not relevant (in fact after version "3" is not supported). The reason for that is that docker needs to be able to change the container name in case you scale your service (multiple versions of the same container might end up running on the same docker instance and then they need to have different container names).

Also when you specify a volume you need to specify full, absolute paths. You can simply replace your volume declaration with what you got from running `docker-compose config` (`C:\Users\roole\instapy-docker\docker-compose:/code:rw`) or you can use $PWD or the equivalent for your OS to refer to your current directory